# Desiging mod counter

Tags: digital-logic, counter, ripple-counter

I came across following question

> The 3 bit ripple counter is to be designed as MOD 4 counter. What should be the architecture of the ‘Logic gate’?
>   [image: Blockquote]
>   A. a 3 bit input AND gate
>   B. a 2 input AND gate
>   C. a NOT gate
>   D. a wire connection (no logic gate needed)

The answer given was:

> In fourth state, Q2 becomes high first time. So it suffices to simply connect Q2 to clear inputs so that all flip flops gets cleared.

I did not get how "fourth state, Q2 becomes high first time".

I tried out the problem myself and I got two different answers:

**Solution 1**

The count will be: 000,001,010,011. So in last count Q0 and Q1 both become HIGH for first time. Hence we should have ANDed them (that is Q0Q1) and applied output of the AND gate to all clear inputs.

**Solution 2**

I tried preparing k map for clear logic:

```
    Q0'Q1'  Q0'Q1  Q0Q1  Q0Q1'
Q2'   0       0     1     0  
Q2    X       X     X     X 
                    |
                    V      
                   Q0Q1
```

From above k map also I got Q0Q1 as reset logic.
However, should we keep reset logic low for four states for mod 4 counter and then make it high in 5th state, like below:

```
    Q0'Q1'  Q0'Q1  Q0Q1  Q0Q1'
Q2'   0       0     0     0  
Q2    1       X     X     X     -> Q2
```

By above k map, we get Q2. This matches with give answer (option D) that simple wire connection will suffice, just connect Q2 to all clear inputs. But I feel
this requires fifth state 100 to occur and then it prevents sixth state by clearing all flip flops.

What is correct here?

Comment: Beware that the reset is a-synchronous! Therefore in your 'solution 1' the outputs are 011 for only a fraction of the time as they immediately get cleared to 0. (In real life this is dangerous as the reset pulse may be so short that not all registers get correctly reset.)

Comment: solution 1 cannot possibly be correct ... the `Logic Gate` is not connected to Q0 or to Q1

Comment: i think that the problem is with terminology ... the question may have been incorrectly translated from another language or transcribed by a layperson .... instead of "fourth state" it should say "state 4" or "state number 4" and it should be qualified with "states are zero based" or "first state is state number 0"

Comment: @Oldfart so whats the solution? I plain wire connection connecting Q2 to clear inputs (as suggested by second kmap) will lead to mod 5 counter (**Q1.** Right?) I feel that the desired logic is Q0Q1 (as suggested by first k map), even though its not possible to achieve in given circuit as `Logic Gate` is not connected to Q1 and Q1 and also it might cause the output 011 to stay for a fraction of moment. (**Q2** Right?) With just Q2 input to `Logic Gate`, it is not possible to substitute anything to `Logic Gate` and achieve mod 4 counter. (**Q3.** Right?)

Comment: For the sake of this assignment you should just do as they expect: use a reset 'spike'. For a real product (a series 10000 or more), I would not like to use it. You may have 1% or 0.1% failing because of this (Or work unreliable e.g. fail when it gets warm). For automotive or medical equipwent this should never be allowed.